# Uploading HTML/CSS Files in bulk to squarespace

Tags: html, css, squarespace

Hi Stack Overflow community,

I'm a bit of a noob here (please be gentle) and wanted to ask how to upload HTML/CSS + Packages in bulk to my site.

I'm familiar with the code injection/CSS editor within Squarespace, but something doesn't seem to be working.

To summarize, I received a bunch of files and was requested to upload them to the website I manage. These files contain:

- HTML (by page)
- CSS (by page)
- image files
- index.html
- Scripts file (which include .js & .php
- sitemap.xml

That being said, I know there is a lot of referencing between these files and wanted to know the best route in incorporating these into my site?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you know if your website is in 'Developer Mode'? The out-of-the-box cms they provide restricts folder management until you switch to the 'Developer Mode'. [more info](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815928-Adding-custom-HTML-CSS-and-JavaScript#toc-developer-mode)

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to upload multiple files is to use the [(S)FTP protocol](http://www.wise-ftp.com/know-how/ftp_and_sftp.htm). You can use an FTP client such as [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) to upload files in bulk to your server.

However, I'm not quite sure if that's possible in your use case. Are you using Squarespace for your project? If so, it looks like you can use either Git or SFTP for file uploads. You'll need to have [developer mode](https://answers.squarespace.com/questions/171179/is-there-ftp-access-to-my-site.html) enabled for that, though.

I found [this article](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205813928-Uploading-and-managing-files) that goes into uploading multiple files to Squarespace via their own upload system, does that help?